# How to check for NaN in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

Also is there a place where I could look up all the floating points ops in Scheme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [this explains it well](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/numbers.html).

Comment: So you could do (eqv? a +nan.0).  That makes me sad - I was going to suggest (= (* a 2) a) -- much more 'interesting'...

Comment: @Aaron: Won't that return true for 0?

Answer (score 2):

In most programming languages, you can determine NaN values by comparing a value with itself.

```
(define (nan? x)
  (not (= x x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [RnRs](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/) document for whatever version of scheme you're using?  Other than that you could try looking at your implementations manual for things that aren't in the language spec.